# Batch edit: delete row call invoke a javascript funtion then delete base on condition

Tags: javascript, .net, telerik, telerik-grid

Work on Asp.net web page application.

[Demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-editing/batch-editing/defaultcs.aspx)

1. Click to add a new record
2. The "Delete" link will appear in the new row - it would be nice to have the same X icon

want to Click "Delete" link - it fires a javascript event then i want a validation process on javascript event then want to delete the row

help me to invoke a javascript event on click delete link.

Answer (score 0):

Check [THIS](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-batch-editing.html) link. The page contains batch edit documentation from Telerik's website. You can find lots of client-side functions, that you can fire, in order to achieve the needed behaviour.

I think you need to use two functions. The first one is:

```
deleteRecord(tableView,row);
```

This function will remove the row, that you want to be removed. You just need to provide the exact row and table.

The second function is:

```
saveChanges(tableView);
```

This function will invoke the methods for saving the grid. As far as I know, the removal of the row won't be saved at all, so you need to find a way to trigger the save. This is one of the ways.

In order to achieve this, you might also need to place a special column for the delete button. For each button then you can set the client function that executes the two mentioned above functions.